# How can I fix this npm error installing electron?

Tags: software-installation, npm, electron

When I use `npm install electron -g`, I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/electron
npm ERR! Refusing to delete /usr/local/bin/electron: ../lib/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/cli.js symlink target is not controlled by npm /usr/local/bin
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/electron
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-03T23_17_02_469Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete the electron folder from `/usr/local/bin` . Then try to install Electron again:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/electron 
sudo npm install -g electron
```